# How to logout a user in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication, logout

I need to force logout a user after his account have been changed in a user management.

The only example I've found is how to logout a current user

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
```

whereas I need to logout an arbitrary  user.

Comment: There's no simple built-in solution for that. You need some kind of extra mechanism implemented to be able to do that. There are a few ways of doing that depending on your exact situation.

Comment: You can accomplish that in the refreshUser() method of your UserProvider.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that if you're using a native php session handler.
Otherwise, it is possible to do that if you store sessions in database, see [PdoSessionHandler to Store Sessions in the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html)